# Why is the key used in the WHERE condition not found as an identifier in php?

Tags: php, sql, pear

I have an *SQL* statement that goes like this:

```
SELECT 
    ISO_id, country_name, gold, silver, bronze, total 
FROM 
    Country 
WHERE 
    ISO_id='GBR';
```

And I use it to receive information from a database via *PHP* and *PEAR*. The database returns `GBR, UK, 29, 17, 19, 65` , meaning that all the information was correctly returned.

Successfully calling and storing the information via *PEAR*:

```
$countryResult =& $db->query($sql);
if(PEAR::isError($countryResult)){
    die($countryResult->getMessage());
}
$row =& $countryResult->fetchRow();
```

Now, if I use `$row['country_name']`, `$row['gold']`, or anything else except `$row['ISO_id']`, then it returns the information correctly as a normal associative array. However, when I use `$row['ISO_id']` I get the error:

> Notice: Undefined index: ISO_id in /disks/olympics/view.php on line
>   100 Call Stack: 0.0004 662648 1. {main}() /disks/olympics/view.php:0

My temporary workaround is calling `ISO_id` twice in the original sql statement and renaming one, which works like so:

```
SELECT 
    ISO_id, ISO_id as iso2, country_name, gold, silver, bronze, total 
FROM 
    Country 
WHERE 
    ISO_id='GBR';

//GBR, GBR, UK, 29, 17, 19, 65
```

Now I can call `$row['iso2']` successfully for what should already work as `$row['ISO_id']`.

For some reason, it looks like using the original `ISO_id` in the `WHERE` clause in the SQL statement messes how I can use it later in the program. Why is that?

Comment: Can ISO_id be NULL? Does every row guarantee to include an ISO_id field?

Comment: @Mari Every row is guaranteed an ISO_id, yes.

Comment: I have a feeling the error is not in the posted code.  Can you post the minimum code needed to duplicate the error?

Comment: I would also question the use of the "=&" assignment by reference operator, "=" may be more appropriate here and may explain some of the unexpected behavior.

Comment: @user700390 Here's a link to the php code in it's entirety: http://pastebin.com/7RWvb6q8. The main difference is that some part are looped (ex: I use a loop of sql statements), but I wanted to make it easier to understand in the post.

Comment: throw a print_r($row) in your fetch loop and post the data that's coming back from the query

Comment: @Notorious, that helped me find it!  ISO_id turns into iso_id on the return...

Array ( [iso_id] => GBR [iso2] => GBR [country_name] => UK [gold] => 29 [silver] => 17 [bronze] => 19 [total] => 65 )

Comment: Very Nice!  :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you print out the `$row` during your *fetch loop* you will see the actual key for the `ISO_id` is being returned by the sql server as all lower case.   So when you try to reference it as `ISO_id` instead of `iso_id` PHP can't find it.

You simply need to change the key to '`iso_id`' , all lowercase and you will be good to go.